# Calculate average per row in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to calculate the average per day from 1 st record of year for each row.
I can do it by iterating in a while loop but am sure that I can achieve this simpler. I woould nee a query to calculate the avgAmount near the Amount field.

The average is simply calculated by summing the amounts and divide by the difference between min and max dates for each row.

```
create table a
(
date  datetime,
dept varchar(50),
amount float
)

insert into a values ('2016-02-07', 'abc', 25)
insert into a values ('2016-02-27', 'abc', 20)
insert into a values ('2016-03-09', 'abc', 30)
insert into a values ('2016-03-28', 'abc', 45)
insert into a values ('2016-04-07', 'abc', 40)
insert into a values ('2016-04-30', 'abc', 50)
insert into a values ('2016-05-07', 'abc', 60)
insert into a values ('2016-05-27', 'abc', 50)
insert into a values ('2016-06-30', 'abc', 38)
insert into a values ('2016-07-17', 'abc', 45)
insert into a values ('2016-07-30', 'abc', 55)
insert into a values ('2016-08-07', 'abc', 70)
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/592a3/7)

Any help please?

Comment: Do you mean, in this case, the sum of the amounts divided by the number of days between 7 February and 7 August? If so, should the results include only data for one department, or should the answer be by each department ?  And what database is this running on ? SQL Server? MySQL? which?

Answer (score 4):

One way to do it is:

```
SELECT date, amount,
AVG(amount) OVER(ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT
ROW) AS AvAmount
FROM a
ORDER BY date
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/592a3/9)

Comment: This is a very elegant solution but unfortunately  "BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW " is not implemented in sql server 2008 where this database resides.

Have tested it in SQLfiddle and the result is good. 
Thabks for your immediate help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
with FirstCalc as
(
select dept, min(date) as MinDate, max(date) as MaxDate, sum(amount) as TotalAmount
from a
group by dept
)
select dept, TotalAmount/datediff(dd, MinDate, MaxDate) as AvePerDay
from FirstCalc
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's SQL Server:

```
Select Sum(a.amount) / datediff(day, start.Date, end.Date)
From a 
  join a start 
    on start.Date = (Select Min(Date) from a
                     Where Year(date) = @Year
                        and dept = a.Dept)
  join a end 
    on end.Date =  (Select Max(Date) from a
                     Where Year(date) = @Year
                        and dept = a.Dept)
Where Year(a.Date) = @year
```